# Guice Startup Database Query

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

I need to perform a database query on play framework startup to retrieve server information. I wrote a ServerInstanceModule ie.

```
public class ServerInstanceModule extends AbstractModule {
ServerInstance serverInstance;

@Override
protected void configure() {

}

@Provides
@Inject
ServerInstance provideServerInstance(Configuration configuration){
    if (serverInstance == null) {
        String serverInstanceId = configuration.getString("instance.db.id");
        try {
            if (serverInstanceId != null) {
                serverInstance = models.managemend.ServerInstance.find.byId(Long.parseLong(serverInstanceId));
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return serverInstance;
}}
```

Is this the right way to go about it? I tried writing a service, declare it as singleton and load it eagerly ie.

```
@Singleton public class ServerInstanceService {
@Inject
private Configuration configuration;

ServerInstance serverInstance;

public ServerInstance get() {
    if (serverInstance == null) {
        String serverInstanceId = configuration.getString("instance.db.id");
        try {
            if (serverInstanceId != null) {
                serverInstance = ServerInstance.find.byId(Long.parseLong(serverInstanceId));
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return serverInstance;
}}
```

but SOMETIMES guice would start with an error because the serverinstance is null. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix this? I would really like to use a service instead of a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing race conditions and thread safety issues. This is the easiest way to achieve it, however `serverInstance` is not thread safe as it could have mutators.

```
@Singleton
public class ServerInstanceService implements IServerInstanceService {

    private final ServerInstance servcerInstance;

    @Inject
    public ServerInstanceService(Configuration config) {
        Long id = // ..
        servcerInstance = ServerInstance.findById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: would i then have a getServerInstance() method?

Comment: Yeah, feel free to enchant the sample code as much as you like.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I see how your solution is better than what I was doing before